# Linux command to kill all MySQL sessions from a specific User?

Tags: mysql, linux, kill

How can i kill all sessions from a user in mysql using a linux command line command? 

 I have a user that is using all on my database connections and insted of killing one by one i want to make a script to kill them all !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Try this :**

```
mysql -uuser -ppassword -e 'show processlist' | grep USER_NAME | awk {'print "kill "$1";"'}| mysql -uuser -ppassword
```

The command will list the processes running in the database and return a `kill 'query id';` command and pipe it into mysql again.
 Be carefull with this command as there is no rollback form it :)

Comment: Thx for Up_One for me ! kk

Comment: When piping back to mysql, use `--force`, since a `KILL` command will fail if by change the connection has already terminated. Without `--force` this will abort all following `KILL` commands.

Answer (score 2):

You may also use `common_schema`'s [kilall()](https://common-schema.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/common_schema/doc/html/killall.html) procedure from within your MySQL server. Use:

```
call killall('evil_user');
```

Disclosure, I am author of this tool.

Comment: very nice !!!!!